# Instant Articles - embedding a tweet

Tags: wordpress, twitter, facebook-instant-articles

Fighting with FB's Instant articles setup for WP. 
Tweet code:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
<p dir="ltr" lang="en">Fewer likes, more learning: <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/VC?src=hash">#VC</a> funding shifting towards <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/AI?src=hash">#AI</a>, away from social media ► <a href="https://blah.com/CKasTR7vDD">https://blah.com/CKasTR7vDD</a></p>
— TechPORTFOLIO (@TechPORTFOLIO) <a href="https://twitter.com/TechPORTFOLIO/status/769631890101899264">August 27, 2016</a>
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" async="" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

after inserting the code to WordPress an iframe with the tweet content is generated. For some reason the tweet's content is not present in the final rendered Instant Articles code so IA transformer apparently doesn't see the iframe with the tweet content ().

I tried to follow the FB guidelines:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/embeds

with no luck... tried to wrap the code above in `<iframe></iframe>` as advised...nope....

This part is carried over:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
    <p dir="ltr" lang="en">Fewer likes, more learning: <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/VC?src=hash">#VC</a> funding shifting towards <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/AI?src=hash">#AI</a>, away from social media ► <a href="https://blah.com/CKasTR7vDD">https://blah.com/CKasTR7vDD</a></p>
    — TechPORTFOLIO (@TechPORTFOLIO) <a href="<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
<p dir="ltr" lang="en">Fewer likes, more learning: <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/VC?src=hash">#VC</a> funding shifting towards <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/AI?src=hash">#AI</a>, away from social media ► <a href="https://blah.com/CKasTR7vDD">https://blah.com/CKasTR7vDD</a></p>
— TechPORTFOLIO (@TechPORTFOLIO) <a href="https://twitter.com/TechPORTFOLIO/status/769631890101899264">August 27, 2016</a>">August 27, 2016</a>
```

but the actual tweet's content  ( https://twitter.com/TechPORTFOLIO/status/769631890101899264 ) is not visible in the final Instant articles rendered code.

Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Try in a simple way,

1) Copy the URL of tweet.

2) Paste the tweet URL on a line in your article/page (as a plain text)
Note : A Tweet link must look like a line, it must be Unlinked.

3) Now Publish it, your tweet will get embedded on your article/page.
If it doesn't work for you, Just edit the page and Unlink the Tweet URL.